# The Jupyter Lab code completion is overager and often gets in the way instead of helping

Tags: jupyter-lab, code-completion

After turning on the code completion in Jupyter Lab, I find myself constantly hitting the Escape key to swat away the constant stream of completely useless suggestions being made. This is an example, where I am typing the word "distance" and get the suggestion "abs".
[image]

This is only an example of the code completion not behaving as expected. Another example is that I can no longer use "tab" to put comments. Another is that I get the same silly list of suggestions starting with "abs" every time I use command+Enter, before I have the chance to type anything in the new cell.

Any suggestions or hints as to how to prevent this annoying behavior?